# Correctly override the generic BaseController

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-5.0

I have the generic BaseController like this:

```
public class BaseController<T> : Controller where T : BaseEntity
{
    protected readonly IRepository _repository;

    public BaseController(IRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    // POST: TController/Create
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public virtual async Task<IActionResult> Create(T item)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                await _repository.AddAsync(item);

            }
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        catch
        {
            return PartialView();
        }
    }
```

Do I correctly override this action in the derived controller class

```
public class PaysController : BaseController<Pays>
{
    public PaysController(IRepository repository): base(repository) { }

    // POST: Pays/Create
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public override async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("IDPays,Code,Nom")] Pays pays)
    {
        return await base.Create(pays);
    }
```

Especially, should I reuse the method attributes(like `ValidateAntiForgeryToken`), and will the binding `Bind` work in that case?

Comment: It is not good idea to keep  you EF code in controller. Think about creating a generic  repository for this instead.

Answer (score 1):

Method attributes do not need to be reused on the overriden method:

```
var attributes = typeof(PaysController).GetMethod("Create").GetCustomAttributes(false);

Debug.Assert(attributes.Any(x => x.GetType() == typeof(HttpPostAttribute)));
Debug.Assert(attributes.Any(x => x.GetType() == typeof(ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute)));
```

The binding `Bind` will work in the overrided method. You will need to mark the base controller as ***abstract***, otherwise ASP.NET Core does not know, which controller and endpoint to choose and throws an exception:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.AmbiguousMatchException: The
> request matched multiple endpoints